# Don't overwrite in <div> but add to <div>

Tags: javascript

I have made a script which shows content in a < div > when you push a button, but when i push another button (while there is already content in the < div >) it overwrites the content. So only the new content shows and the old content disapears.

```
function HandleResponse(response)
{
   document.getElementById('test123').innerHTML = response;
}
```

So the question is: How can I ADD content to a < div > instead of overwriting the content in the < div >? This way I can show multiple content in one < div >.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `+=` the innerHTML of the DIV, which means you add content to the HTML.

```
document.getElementById('test123').innerHTML += response;
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats just a small change :-)

```
function HandleResponse(response)
{
   document.getElementById('test123').innerHTML += response;
}
```